# PHP Curl - Simulate an select option menu selection

Tags: php, html, curl

Guys please check out this HTML code:

```
<select name="dnn$ctr73224$ViewResponsive$sizeDdl" id="sizeDdl" style="display:block">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Please select</option>
        <option value="extra sml" class="greyOut" title="Extra Sml Navy is out of stock">Extra Sml</option>
        <option value="small" title="Small" class="" selected="selected">Small</option>
        <option value="medium" title="Medium" selected="selected">Medium</option>
        <option value="large" title="Large">Large</option>
        <option value="extra lge" title="Extra Lge" class="">Extra Lge</option>
        <option value="xx large" class="greyOut" title="XX Large Navy is out of stock">XX Large</option>
        <option value="xxx large" class="greyOut" title="XXX Large Navy is out of stock">XXX Large</option>
        <option value="xxxx large" class="greyOut" title="XXXX Large Navy is out of stock">XXXX Large</option>

    </select>
```

This is output source code of an HTML page.

AS you can see there is an select menu.

I want to ask is there any way that i can simulate a selection of option via Curl?

I use curl to parse HTML dom elements from this page.

Thanks in advance!